# How to change AppBar title programmatically?

Tags: flutter

Once the screen is built then somehow after some logic I need to change the AppBar title without executing build() method again. How to do this?

Comment: The AppBar's tittle is a Widget (usually a Text()) so if you want to change any widget you must re-execute build().

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can call setState() method inside StatefulWidget and change the title of AppBar. This is how you can do it:

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  String appBarTitle = "Title1";

  void changeTitle(){
    setState(() {
      appBarTitle = appBarTitle == "Title1" ? "Title2" : "Title1";      
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
       child: Scaffold(
         appBar: AppBar(
           title: Text(appBarTitle),
         ),
         floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
           onPressed: changeTitle,
         ),
       ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @stuckedoverflow  you say you don't want `setState()` to come into play and you accept the answer with same logic.

Answer (score 2):

in your State class write

```
String title_string = "your_initial_title";
```

In your appbar write the property:

```
title: Text(title_string)
```

Now whenever you want to change the title write:

```
setState((){
   title_string = "your_new_title";
});
```

Answer (score -3):

**This works for me**

Use it by kotlin user

```
(requireActivity() as MainActivity).supportActionBar?.title = "New title"
```

And for java use this one

```
(( MainActivity) requireActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("New title");
```